# Heroku, bundler fails on missing dependencies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, bundler

I have had trouble recently trying to deploy my rails app on Heroku. In the past, I had deployed apps on Heroku with no problem, but Heroku does not support ruby 2.0.0 anymore. They suggest adding `ruby "2.2.4"` to the `Gemfile`, which is what I did. The beginning of my `Gemfile` is as follows:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby "2.2.4"

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.0'
# Use pg as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
...
```

So, I have run `bundle install` with version 1.7.8 on my computer with no problem. I can even run my app in production mode. However, when I try to deploy the app on Heroku, I get this:

```
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.2.4
-----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.11.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
       Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
       Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Using rake 10.4.2
       Installing i18n 0.7.0
       Installing minitest 5.4.3
       Installing json 1.8.3 with native extensions
       Installing thread_safe 0.3.4
       Installing builder 3.2.2
       Installing erubis 2.7.0
       Your Gemfile.lock is corrupt. The following gem is missing from the DEPENDENCIES
       section: 'mini_portile2'
       Bundler Output: Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
       Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
       Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Using rake 10.4.2
       Installing i18n 0.7.0
       Installing minitest 5.4.3
       Installing json 1.8.3 with native extensions
       Installing thread_safe 0.3.4
       Installing builder 3.2.2
       Installing erubis 2.7.0
       Your Gemfile.lock is corrupt. The following gem is missing from the DEPENDENCIES
       section: 'mini_portile2'
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am not using Heroku Git--I am going through DropBox

Comment: Are you saying that I should run ` heroku config:set BUNDLE_WITHOUT="development:test" ` on the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest deleting your Gemfile.lock, running `bundle install` again locally, committing the new Gemfile.lock to your git repository and then try your `git push heroku master` again.

Comment: @orangeplus same deal. you should try to delete your gemfile.lock. The error message says that it is corrupt, which I would imagine is because when it was originally generated you were using ruby 2.0.x and now you have specified a more recent version. So you need to regenerate your Gemfile.lock with that specification at the top. Not certain, but it seems feasible.

Comment: @orangeplus You're very welcome, I'm glad I was able to help. Pushing to Heroku can be a bitch sometimes. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and what I did was I updated Ruby 2.2.4 in my system and restarted terminal, then followed these steps:

```
bundle install
bundle update 
git push heroku
```

( it’s a good idea to update the gems with bundle update to make sure the versions match)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you only changed the Ruby version number in the `Gemfile`, but did not recreate a valid `Gemfile.lock`. This leads to a `Gemfile.lock` that contains Gems in versions that are not compatible with Ruby 2.2.4.

If you change something in the `Gemfile` then you have to update or recreate the `Gemfile.lock` with the same Ruby version before pushing to Heroku.

I suggest to use a Ruby version manager (like [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) or [RVM](https://rvm.io/)) to be able to run multiple versions of Ruby on your development machine. Then update the Ruby version in your application by changing the Ruby version in `Gemfile` (for Heroku) and `.ruby-version` (for your local environment). Both version must match.

Once that is done, run `bundle install` to update the `Gemfile.lock` or (when there were major updates or you just want to ensure that you use the latest versions) run `bundle update` to recreate the `Gemfile.lock`.